# From a Cygwin bash shell, I'd like the output from a Ruby script to be in UNIX format (without the DOS '\r')

Tags: ruby, pipe, cygwin, stdout

Sorry if this has been answered in previous threads-- I couldn't find any help. In previous versions of Ruby/Cygwin, piping ruby scripts to cygwin progs worked with no problem.

What I have (unwanted DOS format, '\r')...

```js
    $ ruby -e 'puts "x" ' | od -c
    0000000   x  \r  \n
    0000003
```

what I'd like (clean UNIX format for piping)...

```js
    $ echo 'x' | od -c
    0000000   x  \n
    0000002
```

Unusable kludge...

```js
    $ ruby -e 'print "x\n" ' | tr -d '\r' | od -c
    0000000   x  \n
    0000002
```

```
example of how I'm employing the pipe:
>!$ ls -1
IMG_05934.jpg
IMG_05935.jpg
IMG_05938.jpg
k1

$ cat k1
mv -iv IMG_05934.jpg  hawaii_pics_XXX.JPG
mv -iv IMG_05935.jpg  hawaii_pics_XXX.JPG
mv -iv IMG_05938.jpg  hawaii_pics_XXX.JPG 

$ ruby number.rb k1 | sh
'IMG_05934.jpg' -> 'hawaii_pics_100.JPG'$'\r'
'IMG_05935.jpg' -> 'hawaii_pics_101.JPG'$'\r'
'IMG_05938.jpg' -> 'hawaii_pics_102.JPG'$'\r' 

$ ls -1
'hawaii_pics_100.JPG'$'\r'
'hawaii_pics_101.JPG'$'\r'
'hawaii_pics_102.JPG'$'\r'
k1


Cygwin, Ruby and Windows versions used:
>!$ uname -v
2021-12-03 16:35

$ ruby --version
ruby 3.0.3p157 (2021-11-24 revision 3fb7d2cadc) [x64-mingw32]

Windows 11Pro
```

Comment: are you using the Cygwin version of ruby ?

Comment: No. Separate ruby download from ruby-lang.org.

Comment: A windows program will use a windows style line termination.

Comment: Pipe the output through the `dos2unix` command to convert CR+LF to LF line endings. See `dos2unix --help` for more info.

Comment: Thank you. I did something similar...
function myruby () { ruby $@ | tr -d '\r'; }